# Force TZ when connecting Java to PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timezone

I have two Java apps that connect to a PostgreSQL database via Hibernate and JPA. Is there a way for their connection to mimic the `set timezone` command, such that for the duration of the connection, the timezone is set differently than what's default for the DB?

Comment: Why would that matter? The date objects read by the JDBC driver don't reflect the session time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since [commit 9d6b7930e6](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/commit/9d6b7930e660b8e0f750920c791197c2257f1695) from 2011, the JDBC driver sets the session time zone from the JVM default time zone. See the documentation of [`java.util.TimeZone.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--) for details how that is determined:

> - Use the `user.timezone` property value as the default time zone ID if it's available.
> - Detect the platform time zone ID. The source of the platform time zone and ID mapping may vary with implementation.
> - Use GMT as the last resort if the given or detected time zone ID is unknown.

So the easiest way is to set the `user.timezone` property when you start the JVM:

```bash
java -Duser.timezone=UTC -cp ... MyProgram
```

Comment: With the latest Postgresql JDBC lib (42.5.4), using `&options=-c%20timezone%3DUTC` failed for me :

Clearly, a timezone parameter is sent to the server side this way, because it can have your connexion failing if not set with a valid timezone reference.

**BUT**, it's not (anymore ?) taken into account by the PGSQL server side. 

See the reply to this GH issue on pgjdbc repo : https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/2439

So I guess the only valid option left is to change the client side TZ at JVM level ... :(

Comment: @Lemmy The PostgreSQL backend won't ignore a parameter that was set, so the only explanation is that the JDBC driver does not set it. Run `SHOW timezone` via the JDBC driver to see what is set in PostgreSQL. I can imagine that the driver explicitly overrides the parameter (set `log_min_duration_statement = 0` and look out for `SET` statements). I'll have a look if I find the time.

Comment: @Lemmy I researched, and my answer was wrong. I have fixed it.

Comment: yep. On one hand, I think it's sad not been able to choose the TZ context in which one an opened connection with a PGSQL server is going to take place. But on the other hand, when you really need to manage multiple TZ, most of the times those connections are taken from a connection pool, and thus it wouldn't be practical at all to take advantage of both. Thanks for the feedback anyway !!